# Jest - Vue test utils - How to assert callback function of window eventlistener?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

Im trying to check if a function is being call when resize event fired.

"@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.3"
"vue": "^2.7.14"
"jest": "27.1.0"

Component.vue

```
export default {
 props: {},
 data() {
   this.timer = null,
   this.stoppedForce = false
 },
 methods :{
    manageTimers(){
      if (this.$el.querySelector('[data-wrapper-adTVU]')){
         clearTimeout(this.timer)
      }else{
         this.resetTimer()
      }
    },
    resetTimer(){
      clearTimeout(this.timer)
      if (this.stoppedForce) {return}
      this.timer = setTimeout( ()=> if(){}else{}, 2000)
    }
 },
 mounted () {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.manageTimers)
 }

}
```

Component.test.js

```
import myComponent from /.Componnet
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'

describe('Component test', () => {
  it('should trigger manageTimes', () => {

  const wrapper = shallowMount(myComponent, {attachTo: window.document.body } )
  const spyManager = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'manageTimes')

  const event = new CustomEvent('resize')

  window.dispatchEvent(event)

  expect(window.addEventListener).toBeCalledWith('resize',expect.any(Function))
  expect(spyManager).toHaveBeenCalled()
  }
}
```

I have tried:

1. mocking the window.addEventListener but didn't work.

```
window.addEventListener = jest.fn((event, callback) => {
  events[event] = callback
})
```

2. SpyOn window dispatch:
   This worked to this expectations, but it is not what I need

```
const dispatchEventSpy = jest.spyOn(window, 'dispatchEvent')

//same code of above for wrapper and dispatching event.

//Gives OK for:

expect(dispatchEventSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Event))
expect(dispatchEventSpy.mock.calls[0][0].type).toBe('resize')
```

3. Cheking timer value. But got Received: null.

```
expect(wrapper.vm.timer).not.toBeNull()
```

Need: I just wanna check if the callback function "manageTimes" from that window "resize" eventListener is being called.
Would appreciatte it if some of you could help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi! 
"Im trying to check if a function is being call when resize event fired."
You do not have to test that. Actually you should not test that. That is done by `window`. You have to test your code. Your code calls `window.addEventListener`, so you have to test this. You also can assert your callback with `mockFn.mock.calls` https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api/#mockfnmockcalls

Comment: I would do this:
`const manageTimerCallback = addEventListenerMock.mock.calls[0][1];`

`manageTimerCallback();`

`// assert expected things when resize happens`